# Database design for millions of posts

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I have this issue. I have three types of posts a user can generate (some users can generate all some can only generate one type).  I have the following types: main, employee and admin posts.

I expect to have to deal with millions of posts (all three types).  But about 90% of all posts would be `main_posts`. Also, most reads from the DB would be of the `main_posts` too.

**NOTE**
The `main_posts` table would have about 50-100 more fields than what is currently there. **update**
those fields would be normalized into different tables. The ideea is that the main-posts table would have the bulk of the posts and therefore would have the most reads and writes.

Which design option is more sound?

Option1
[image: Option 1]

or Option 2
[image: Option 2]

Thank you.

Comment: I think that you could (possibly - don't know the full scenario) greatly simplify your design with just one post table with a post_category field with values 'emp', 'admin' or 'main'. Have you considered this option?

Comment: Well, I forgot to add that the main_posts table would have another 50-100 extra fields. The simplified design would not work!

Comment: Hang those extra fields off the main post table? Just throwing ideas out there!

Comment: @Vérace I will add them but was wondering which option would be better.

Comment: The problem is that both designs could probably be made to work with accompanying code - it's very difficult to give definitive advice in such situations. I know from experience that you can start with a design and as you're coding, you're modifying the design constantly. Basically, if I were you, I'd prototype both and gradually evolve a design rather than try and definitively start with something and rigidly stick to it. I'm sorry that I cannot be more helpful, but some questions are impossible to answer with a simple "yes, you **should** pick no. 2".

Comment: @Vérace Thanks your the input. I am not really asking for a yes or no answer, and rather like to get input on to which option would be better considering just a small angle of what I need to do. Basically the two option are not really different but I feel that when it comes to millions of records the two options can make a big difference. I am inclined to take Option 2 since I can directly (one join only) access the main_posts (this is where the large number of posts are). I am not sure on what other options there are and hopefully someone who already went through something like this can help

Comment: OK - I'll give you my **opinion**. Option 2 looks better to me too - since it looks "cleaner". Take a look [here](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) for potential ideas. Just a thought - IMHO, a table with more than 30 fields should start to get one interested in the design - tables are like women - they should be tall and slim (many records, not many fields) rather than short and fat (few records, many fields) :-)

Comment: Just a small note - having 50-100 columns in one table is often not the right thing. Will all of them be filled or mostly null? Will they be all of the same type? Could you just store them as rows in a separate table instead?

Comment: @jkavalik I wasn't explocit enough. Yes there would be 50 to 100 more fields but they would be normalized into different tables. But they would be linked to the main_posts table.

Comment: @Cristian ah, ok then :) still it could be probably done with one table and a `post_category` field as suggested in the first comment, all those other tables should work OK with that (not saying its the right thing, just that it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

Read this post how StackExchange does it:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/how-to-query-the-stackexchange-databases/

Answer (score 1):

Coding your application should not drive your database design. You should first write down the biz rules of your app. It seems you have different type of users (employee, admin and regular users), which mean they'll have different needs. 
Option2 seem a good approach. User table should have userType. REgarding the images, do they belong to the user (they post them) or it's in the application? If image belongs to user, then you should have User_image table. If image can be shared between different user_type then your design in option 2 is correct. Make sure to write down all the business rules, it will help you design your database and speed up your coding development (less db modification).