# Database design to handle millions of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, scalability, big-data

We are running an application that is  collecting data much faster than we anticipated. Trying to addapt to that, we are doing a redesig of the database.
After reading [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121625/database-design-for-millions-of-posts), [this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/how-to-query-the-stackexchange-databases/) and [this](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/10/01/one-million-tables-mysql-8-0/), I am not sure what the best approach for our design is... considering our HW is very humble.

There are three main tables that are causing problems:

- SCANS
- DOMAINS
- DOCUMENTS
- VALUES

Currently we have one single table to store data. The relation between them is:

- 1 **SCAN** -> (avg 4x) **DOMAINS** -> (avg 3000) MANY **DOCUMENTS** -> (avg 51000) MANY **VALUES**

  - 1 SCAN points to average 4 entries on DOMAINS.
  - 4 entries on DOMAINS point to average 12.000 entries ON DOCUMENTS
  - 12000 entries ON DOCUMENTS point TO average 204000 entries on VALUES

We are currently performing around 100 scans/day. That is inserting around 20.400.000 items per day into VALUES.

We are considering to split VALUES table as one "VALUE_table_per_month":

- **VALUES_year_month** with the intention to distribute the load between them. But if we multiply the number of scanners, this mechanism is not escalable.
- **VALUES_year_month_day** then we will end up with so many tables into the same DB.

In both cases, if we increase the number of scans per day, none of the solutions seems scalable.

At this point, to keep all the data into a centralized DB does not seem the best option for scalability reasons... but at the same time, a distributed system will increase the load time significantly.

What would be a reasonable approach? I am sure we are not the first team to find this issue! :P

**EDIT**

*How much data do we read per query?*

That depends on the SCAN. Not all scans have the same amount of data. The range varies between:

- 1 SCAN --> 200 VALUES
- 1 SCAN --> 200.000 VALUES

The information is presented on a front end to the end user. So we have splitted how the queries are requested to the backend to avoid overload the server, but in some cases it is not enought due the high number of VALUES.

*When is the data read?*

That entirely depends on the end users. Some days they read 10s of SCANS a day, others none and others 100s.

**EDIT II**
ANALYZE DESCRIBE results from two queries. First one quick and second one slow.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT value,
        url,
        filetype, 
        severity,
        COUNT(id_value) AS data_count
FROM VALUES
WHERE (weigth = 150 OR weigth = 100) 
AND id_analysis = 23 
AND is_hidden = 0 
AND is_hidden_by_user = 0 
GROUP BY value 
ORDER BY data_count DESC
```

**Result 1:**

```
| -> Sort row IDs: data_count DESC  (actual time=34.016..34.016 rows=0 loops=1)
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=34.006..34.006 rows=0 loops=1)
    -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=34.005..34.005 rows=0 loops=1)
        -> Filter: ((VALUES.is_hidden_by_user = 0) and (VALUES.is_hidden = 0) and ((VALUES.weigth = 150) or (VALUES.weigth = 100)))  (cost=1.00 rows=0.05) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=1)
            -> Index lookup on VALUES using id_analysis (id_analysis=23)  (cost=1.00 rows=1) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=1)
```

|

Result 2:

```
    | -> Sort row IDs: data_count DESC  (actual time=187172.159..187172.173 rows=136 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=187172.079..187172.111 rows=136 loops=1)
        -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=187172.077..187172.077 rows=136 loops=1)
            -> Filter: ((VALUES.is_hidden_by_user = 0) and (VALUES.is_hidden = 0) and ((VALUES.weigth = 150) or (VALUES.weigth = 100)))  (cost=264956.35 rows=695) (actual time=249.030..186775.012 rows=52289 loops=1)
                -> Index lookup on VALUES using id_analysis (id_analysis=8950)  (cost=264956.35 rows=265154) (actual time=248.979..186696.529 rows=134236 loops=1)
 |
```

**EDIT III**

> Consider `PARTITION`ing

This is a great suggestion. Kudos!. From what I have read now, that is the native equivalent to spliting tables in the way we were consideting to do.

> `(weigth = 150 OR weigth = 100)` is a rather strange test.

Removing the `OR` clausule improves the timing:

```
| -> Sort row IDs: data_count DESC  (actual time=101261.260..101261.271 rows=113 loops=1)
    -> Table scan on <temporary>  (actual time=101261.187..101261.216 rows=113 loops=1)
        -> Aggregate using temporary table  (actual time=101261.185..101261.185 rows=113 loops=1)
            -> Filter: ((VALUES.is_hidden_by_user = 0) and (VALUES.is_hidden = 0) and (VALUES.id_analysis = 8950) and (VALUES.weigth = 150))  (cost=79965.29 rows=623) (actual time=83848.835..100942.179 rows=52259 loops=1)
                -> Intersect rows sorted by row ID  (cost=79965.29 rows=62292) (actual time=83848.830..100908.758 rows=52259 loops=1)
                    -> Index range scan on VALUES using id_analysis over (id_analysis = 8950)  (cost=291.66 rows=265154) (actual time=0.100..443.145 rows=134236 loops=1)
                    -> Index range scan on VALUES using weigth over (weigth = 150)  (cost=13492.63 rows=12380386) (actual time=0.043..83511.686 rows=7822871 loops=1)
 |
```

> Please elaborate on `value` versus `id_value`

I believe it might be just a "bad naming".

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_value          | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_document       | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_tag            | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value             | mediumtext  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| weigth            | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_analysis       | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| url               | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| domain            | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| filetype          | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| severity_name     | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| id_domain         | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_city           | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| city_name         | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_hidden         | tinyint     | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| id_company        | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_hidden_by_user | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: It's a good amount of data being written daily, but about how much of it do you ever read at any given time (i.e. per query)?

Comment: @J.D. I have edited the question with the answer to your (good) question.

Comment: Thanks, but a little more details on that answer would be helpful. More so, an example of the query that would be used to read the data with an example of how much data that query would return would be great! Would a single query return 100 `SCANS` at the same time, or more so the same query would be ran numerous times throughout the day but only return a few scans each time it's ran? And when you say 100 `SCANS` does that include all the related data, so we're talking 20.4 million rows, or you mean literally 100 rows of just the `SCANS` data?

Comment: We can assume each query will only return information about one scan. And each scan can contain between 200 rows and 200k rows. The qqueries performance is another aspect that is address with offsets and loops. That can be worked out. Now the issue is when we store data, search into that table is problematic.It currently has 60M rows and each "SELECT" takes too long sometimes.

Comment: "*search into that table is problematic.It currently has 60M rows and each "SELECT" takes too long sometimes.*" - Exactly why seeing an example query (actually the exact query with an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` would be ideal) for reading the data is important. 60 million rows is a small table, so `SELECT`ing small amounts of data (e.g. 200k rows or less) at a time should be rather quick. In fact, it shouldn't matter how big your table is in number of rows, if you're always `SELECT`ing a relatively small amount of data from it. I say this with experience with tables in the 10 billions of rows.

Comment: Just added one example of each case under "EDIT II".

Comment: `is_hidden_by_user` -- Does this mean you can hide each "value" individually??

Comment: @RickJames, Yes. On the user interface, there is an option where a user can mark a value to be hidden. That is in case the automated system for classification assign a "SEVERITY" that is not correct, the user can "HIDE" it manually

Answer (score 8):

Do not split a table simply because it is big.
Consider `PARTITIONing` a big table if you need to delete "old" data.
Do consider 'sharding' when the number of writes become too big for a single machine.

250 rows inserted per second on SSD device does *not*, by itself, trigger any of the above reasons to split.

If you have a retention period of, say, 2 months, then `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` and doing a monthly `DROP PARTITION` + `REORGANIZE PARTITION` is advisable.  More discussion:  [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

`(weigth = 150 OR weigth = 100)` is a rather strange test.  Are there no values between 100 and 150, or do you deliberately filter them out?  I ask because `OR` complicates optimization.

The query you presented needs

```
INDEX(id_analysis, is_idden, is_hidden_by_user, weight)
```

The query is improperly written because of `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.  I doubt if `url, filetype, and severity` are "dependent" on `value`.

Please elaborate on `value` versus `id_value`.  This sounds like another mistake in the query.

Please elaborate on why `Documents` and `Values` are separate.  It smells like "over-normalization".

Or maybe I am really confused by the name `VALUES` because of it containing url, filetype, severity.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

In Data Warehouse situation, [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) are often the answer to performance.  Can you summarize the counts for each day, then sum up those subtotals?

Comment: Removing the "OR" clausule improves the time. I added  details on "EDIT III".

Comment: @JaviM I didn't get a chance to reply earlier, but agreed `OR` in the predicates (`JOIN`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` clauses) is notorious for complicating execution plans. Usually a more *efficient* workaround is to use `UNION` with the same query twice, once for each value of the `OR` condition. Aside from that, Rick is correct in terms of better indexing, table design, and query optimization will all contribute to the performance you seek without needing to worry about splitting your data up across tables, shards, or even thinking about partitioning.

Answer (score 2):

### INDEX(id_analysis, weight)

Most of the query time was spent index scanning/lookup on these two columns. Putting them together will discourage the planner from index scanning `weight` alone and reading 7,822,871 rows from `values` to compare against 134,236 read from scanning over `id_analysis`.

This index should allow the `Filter: ((VALUES.is_hidden_by_user = 0) and (VALUES.is_hidden = 0)` to be pipelined for almost no cost as the temp table is being created for aggregation.

Comment: It's too bad mysql doesn't fully support partial indexes. This would be a slam dunk use-case for a partial index with `WHERE (weigth = 150 OR weigth = 100) AND is_hidden = 0 AND is_hidden_by_user = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Purely from a disk IO stand point.

Move your database onto a SSD or better yet a NVMe storage.

SSD up to 550mb/s
NVMEe 3000mb/s plus can be achieved.

Also, I was taught to get your data in 5th normal form.  Then only change it from that in the few conditions where it makes sense.